# How do I calculate ¨Newtonian constant of gravitation over $\hbar c$¨ to get to the value in NIST?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, physical-constants, si-units, absolute-units

I know this is a silly question, the definition of the value is the formula for the value itself but I have tried putting the constants in and I am not getting the same answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Link to NIST Page <https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?bgspu|search_for=gravitation>

Comment: You probably have some problem with units. Please show the values for $G$, $\hbar$, and $c$ that you are using.

Comment: It is hard to determine what you are doing wrong if you do not show your work.

Comment: 6.67*10^-11/(299792458*1.05*10^-34)

Comment: Those values, along with their *units*, belong in the question, not in comments.

Comment: If you keep the units in your calculation, you will see that your result has units kg$^{-2}$. You then have to convert this to the units on the NIST page, which are $(\text{GeV}/c^2)^{-2}$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach may be helpful:

$$
G=6.674 \times 10^{-11} \frac{m^{3}}{{kg} \cdot {s}^{2}} \times \frac{ 1kg}{5.61020 \times 10^{26} \frac{GeV}{c^{2}}} \times \frac{c^{2}}{8.98755178\times 10^{16} \frac{m^{2}}{s^{2}}} \times \frac{1 {GeV}^{-1}}{1.9733 \times 10^{-16} m}= \\ 6.70810 \times 10^{-39} \left(\frac{GeV}{c^{2}}\right)^{-2}
$$

The first conversion factor comes from

$$
E=mc^{2}
$$

converting $1kg$ to $\frac{E}{c^{2}}$.  The second factor is from the speed of light

$$
c = 2.99792458 \times 10^{8} \frac{m}{s}
$$

and the last factor is from the following reference:
[https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~amyers/NaturalUnits.pdf](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Eamyers/NaturalUnits.pdf)

converting $m$ to $GeV$.

I hope this helps.